# Problem with boost : ‘timer’ is not a member of ‘boost’

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to install a package called Siconos, which uses python and its libraries, and also C++ and other libraries such as oce and occ.
It is installed correctly but when I run a C++ code using Siconos it is giving me the follwoing Boost error,

```
|===========================================================|
| Siconos software, version 4.4.0 - Copyright 2021 INRIA    |
|                                                           |
| Free software under Apache 2.0 License.                   |
|===========================================================|

[ Generate CMakeLists.txt file in /scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/.siconos ]


[------------------- Configure project (cmake) --------------------]

-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/.siconos

[---------------------- Build project (make) ----------------------]

[ 33%] Built target BallPlugin
Scanning dependencies of target BouncingBallTS
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BouncingBallTS.dir/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:147:12: error: ‘progress_display’ is not a member of ‘boost’
     boost::progress_display show_progress(N);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:149:12: error: ‘timer’ is not a member of ‘boost’
     boost::timer time;
            ^~~~~
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:150:10: error: request for member ‘restart’ in ‘time’, which is of non-class type ‘time_t(time_t*) noexcept {aka long int(long int*) noexcept}’
     time.restart();
          ^~~~~~~
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:162:9: error: ‘show_progress’ was not declared in this scope
       ++show_progress;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:167:41: error: request for member ‘elapsed’ in ‘time’, which is of non-class type ‘time_t(time_t*) noexcept {aka long int(long int*) noexcept}’
     cout << "Computation Time " << time.elapsed()  << endl;
                                         ^~~~~~~
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:180:10: error: ‘SiconosException’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘SiconosVector’?
   catch (SiconosException& e)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          SiconosVector
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp:182:13: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
     cerr << e.report() << endl;
             ^
CMakeFiles/BouncingBallTS.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BouncingBallTS.dir/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BouncingBallTS.dir/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BouncingBallTS.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BouncingBallTS.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/siconos", line 826, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/siconos", line 151, in main
    build_project(args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/siconos", line 768, in build_project
    run_command(cmake_build_command, args.quiet)
  File "/usr/local/bin/siconos", line 799, in run_command
    subprocess.run(command, check=True, **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/.siconos', '--target', 'install', '--']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe the code `/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/siconos-tutorials/examples/mechanics/BouncingBall/BouncingBallTS.cpp` is missing an include. [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely missing the necessary `#include` file.
Boost files and others may include other files, but are unspecified as to what else they include (commonly referred to as "dragging in").  This means that if you forget to `#include` something, it might work anyway because it was nested inside another header.  But after an update, or under a different configuration, that no longer works because the internal include files have changed.

You should check the [Boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html) for the correct include file for that symbol, and add it to the top of whichever file contains the error.  This may be necessary for several files.